# Running command while zenity dialog box is shown in bash

Tags: bash, zenity

I want to show an info box, or a general message, while running a command in background but i can't find an option to do so with zenity. Is it possible in the first place?

An example would be this, for better explanation

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --info --text "I'm doing big things behind this window!"
any_command
```

With this, `any_command` (which obviously is a placeholder for... any command you'd like:D) will be execute ONLY AFTER I close the info window. Can I have the two running at the same time without using a progress bar? And is it possible, when `any_command` finishes, killing the previous info window and display another? (Or change the text in the first one, it does not matter...)

I could do

```
zenity --info --text "I've done this: `any_command`"
```

but that leaves me without any notice about what's happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about sending your first `zenity` to the background, and killing it when the command is done?

```
#! /bin/bash
zenity --info --text="Running something, sit tight." &
zpid=$!
sleep 10
kill $zpid
zenity --info --text="Done :)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the command line:

```
zenity --info --text="listing files" && ls -l > temp.txt |\
  zenity --progress --pulsate && \
  zenity --text-info --filename=temp.txt --width=800 --height=600
```